# Undocumented opencv function?

Tags: function, opencv

may I know what is the difference between an "UNDOCUMENTED" opencv function with a documented one? I have searched online but apparently I do not get the explanation that is clear enough to make me clear my doubt. Thanks

The function is calcBluriness, which is used to determine the blurriness of a given image. Thanks

Comment: You should probably add more detail about which function you think is undocumented etc. AFAIK the whole library is documented here https://docs.opencv.org/

Comment: The function is added. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d50/group__videostab.html#ga527fd10de0ee99ed7585d4a7dc23c470

Answer (score 1):

This question is rather a non question, but here is an answer anyway in case of future viewers.

All of OpenCV is documented, and documentation is part of the development process, you can access the docs [here](https://docs.opencv.org/)

As for calcBluriness, it is also documented, you can find that [here](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/d50/group__videostab.html#ga527fd10de0ee99ed7585d4a7dc23c470)

Comment: calcBusiness? :)

Comment: Just to add my 2 cents, sometimes something may be missing in the latest available online doc (or python docs), but if you build the docs from the sources it may appeared.